# Can we conserve angular momentum of a rod (not hinged) about its centre of mass when its centre of mass has a acceleration?

Tags: rotational-dynamics

The rod is not hinged. Mass of rod M and length L which is initially at rest

Answer (score 0):

Angular momentum can be conserved when there is no net torque, so this depends upon the location of the force causing the COM to accelerate, if it is gravitational then the force is acting at COM and you can conserve the angular momentum about it.Otherwise, it can be conserved about the point of application of force and hence, torque.The COM is irrelevant if you're looking to conserve angular momentum in the general scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The acceleration of the center of mass, CM, $\vec a_{CM}$ is determined by $\vec F_{ext} = m \vec a_{CM}$ where $\vec F_{ext}$ is the external force and $m$ the mass. The change in angular momentum about the CM is ${d \vec L_{CM} \over dt} = \vec M_{ext}$ where $\vec L_{CM}$ is the angular momentum about the CM, and $\vec M_{ext}$ is the net torque about the CM; this is true even if the CM is accelerating.

You can have a net force causing acceleration of the CM and no net torque about the CM.  For example, a body in free fall under gravity has no torque about the CM because the force of gravity acts at the CM.  Or, a body with downward forces applied at points in the body where the locations cause the total torque to be zero.